# A proof about a spectrum radius inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, spectral-radius

Let U$_i$ $\in$ $\Bbb R^{n×v_i}$ be a matrix composed of unit orthogonal vectors, U = diag{U$_i$} i $\in$ {1,2,...N}. For instance
\begin{matrix}
U_1=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix} \qquad U_2 =\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}  \\
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}   \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
then $$
    U =\left [ \begin{matrix}
    0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \\
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
   \end{matrix} \right ]            ​
$$

So is that true for any matrix $\phi$ whose spectrum radius is less than 1, the spectrum radius of $U^ \mathrm{T}$ $\phi$ U is less than one. i.e. $\rho$($\phi$) < 1 $\Longrightarrow$ $\rho$($U^ \mathrm{T}$ $\phi$ U) < 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counter example:
$$
  U=\pmatrix{1 \cr 0},\quad\text{and}\quad   \phi=\pmatrix{2 &2 \cr -2 & -2}.
  $$
We have  that $\rho(\phi)=0$, but $\rho(U^T\phi U)=2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So can we add some constrains to make the inequality true?